# strophe.roster (backbone-xmpp library) and Strophe.muc plugins collide

Tags: backbone.js, strophe

I use Strophe.muc plugin and the backbone-xmpp's strophe.roster plugin ([backbone-xmpp](https://github.com/ggozad/strophe.plugins) ) and if I use both simultaniously the presence stanzas (sometimes) will not be handled by any of the specified handlers. Is this because both plugins listen for presence stanzas and therefore block each other?

How do I isolate them from each other, so that they do not collide?